# Methods for contactless logon/logoff for a Windows workstation?

Tags: security

I'd like to use some method to automatically log me out from my workstation when I walk away from it.

The Bluetooth connection on my phone could be a good method to do this - do you know of any software that uses this method, or others for contactless logoff?

Comment: Do you want the system to completely _log you out_ or to _lock the screen_? A full logout can become _really_ annoying.

Comment: Just locking the screen would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have played with [BtProx](http://btprox.sourceforge.net/), but it was a bit hit and miss.

*"BtProx is a small Windows application working both under Windows XP and Vista. I never tested it under Windows 2000, but there's no reason why it should not work. It locks your computer when you go away from it. It locks on one of your Bluetooth devices which are paired to the the machine. When you walk away from the computer the device is disconnected and the computer is locked after timeout."*

Comment: IIRC, with the Bluetooth API used, BtProx can only do boolean "reachable/not reachable" checks. It would be better if it used the signal strength ("RSSI"?), but I'm not even sure the Windows Bluetooth stack provides access to this value.